# Parsing HTML In iOS Using TFHpple?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios

Iam New To iOS .
i Wanna Parse HTML Page Like This :

```
<div class="main_menu">
          <ul class="sf-menu">
            <li class="current"><a href="#" class="sifrme_active">Holiday Tours</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="about-holiday-tours.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="Mohammed-el-decken.html">Mohammed El Decken</a></li>
                <li><a href="Yehia-El-Decken.html">Yehia El Decken</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="sifrme_active">Vacation Packages</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="Slov-2-Spain.html">Slov2Spain</a></li>
                <li><a href="Swiss-Alps.html">Swiss Alps</a></li>
                <li><a href="fall-hike.html">Fall Hike</a></li>
                <li><a href="nile-valley.html">Nile Valley</a></li>
                <li><a href="sahlala.html">Sahlala</a></li>
                <li><a href="Safar-El-Layaly.html">Safar El Layaly</a></li>
                <li><a href="cruising-sinai.html">Cruising Sinai</a></li>
                <li><a href="siwa-oasis.html">Siwa Siwa</a></li>
                <li><a href="Silk-Road.html">Silk-Road</a></li>
                <li><a href="French-Alps.html">French Alps</a></li>
              </ul>

            </li>
     ->         <li><a href="#">Weekend Trips</a><ul>
     ->         <li><a href="hiking.html">Hiking</a></li>
     ->         <li><a href="Sandboarding.html">Sandboarding</a></li>
     ->         <li><a href="Horseriding.html">Horse Riding</a></li>
     ->         <li><a href="GoCycle.html">GoCycle</a></li>
     ->         <li><a href="Islamic-Tour.html">Islamic Tour</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="holiday-tours-reservation.html">Reservation</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

i wanna Access Weekend trips   Where The Arrows And I Cannot Fine XPathQuery To Get Them ?
Any Help Please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *data = [xpath searchWithXPathQuery:@"//li//a//child::text()"];
```

to search data

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
  TFHppleElement *element = [data objectAtIndex:i];
  NSLog(@"%@", [element content]);
}
```

to look data inside and you can check how to get you want.

And here is a xPath syntax tutorial page:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: First Thank You for Your Answer It Works Good , but it retrieve to me all data i need    where arrows only .

Comment: You can look the page I mentioned above.
In Predicates section, I think you can find what you want.

Comment: For example: you can add a attribute in your html.
<li><a href="#" customType="week">Weekend Trips</a><ul>
and use //li//a[@type='week']//child::text() to find it.